# Change "right" / "left" slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have 5 images wrapped in a absolutely positioned div. When I click "next" button I set div's `right: 0` and when I click "previous" button I set div's `left: 0`.

So it behaves like a horizontal slider of images.

What I need now is to add animation to this transition. I want this div to "move" slowly.

I tried this:

`$('.slider').animate({right:'0'}, 1000);`

Instead of `$('.slider').css('right','0');`

But it didn't work. The div moves to the right with no animation.

Here is the code with snippet:

```js
$('.arrow-right').on('click', function() {  
        $('.slider').attr('style', '');
        $('.slider').css('right','0');
        $('.arrow').toggle();
    });

    $('.arrow-left').on('click', function() {
    $('.slider').attr('style', '');
        $('.slider').css('left','0');
        $('.arrow').toggle();
    });
```

```css
.container {
    height: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: grey;
    width: 420px;
}

.arrow {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

.arrow-left {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 47px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

.arrow-right {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 47px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
}

.slider img {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="arrow hide">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left arrow-left"></i>
            </span>
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
    <img src="4.jpg">
    <img src="5.jpg">
  </div>
  <span class="arrow">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right arrow-right"></i>
            </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot animate an absolute dive from `left:0` to `right:0`.

You need to calculate left position and animate from 0 to new left.
Also `$('.slider').attr('style', '');` will remove `position:absolute`, so just comment it.

```
$('.arrow-right').on('click', function() {  
    //$('.slider').attr('style', '');
    var left = $('.slider').outerWidth() - $('.container').outerWidth();
    $('.slider').animate({left:'-'+left+'px'}, 1000);
    $('.arrow').toggle();
});

$('.arrow-left').on('click', function() {
    //$('.slider').attr('style', '');
    $('.slider').animate({left:'0'}, 1000);
    $('.arrow').toggle();
});
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdaoz7dg/10/)